# Привет всем, как использовать числа в списке которые допустим равны в диапазоне от 500 до 1500. помогите пожалуйста. Желательно на python

Tags: python

```
dataNew = [12, 111,999, 333333, 22222222, 408, 1142, 326, 734, 45, 281,]
x <= 500 and x >= 1500
dex = dataNew[:x]
print(dex)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129486/discussion-on-question-by--------).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И так правильно

```
if iteam >= 500 and iteam <= 1500:
```

и так

```
if 500 <= iteam <= 1500:
```

Comment: Почему то не работает.

Comment: напишите что именно вы делаете и как 'не работает' если есть ошибки, то добавьте их полный текст в вопрос

Comment: Покажите кусок кода

Comment: щас попробую весь код написать.

Comment: Редактируйте вопрос, там напишите

Comment: Слушайте хорошая штука оверфлоу)

Comment: @КамильШамбилов Просто прежде чем задавать вопрос, следует ознакомиться с правилами ;)